# Чем отличается переменная экземпляра от переменной метода?

Tags: java

Чем отличается переменная экземпляра от переменной метода?

Я как понял переменная метода которая находится в теле метода, а не его параметры. Переменная экземпляра которая находится в классе, но не статичная.

Comment: Где вы встретили такие определения? Переменная экземпляра - это нонсенс. У экземпляра может быть только поле. А переменная метода - это тавтология.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev дословно так и есть =) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable

Comment: в целом Ваши утверждения верны

Comment: Что значит чем? Банально тем, что метод это другая область видимости и определенные переменные внутри не будут доступны снаружи.

Comment: http://proglang.su/java/variable-types не плохой материал

Comment: @StrangerintheQ к счастью для меня, никогда не встречал подобного запутывающего перевода в учебниках. Впрочем, и в англоязычных не припомню использования термина именно в таком виде.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev в литературе по java чаще конечно это `member`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Я какие только книги не читал, везде переменная экземпляра везде светиться, я вот и не пойму что за))

Answer (score 1):

Переменная экземпляра (aka поле, aka переменная-член) описывается внутри описания класса, вне тела методов, без слова `static`. Физически каждый экземпляр объекта имеет свой собственный набор таких переменных, в отличие от статических переменных (переменных класса), которые являются общими для всех экземпляров. Соответственно, значения таких переменных могут быть разными для разных экземпляров объекта. Время жизни таких переменных -- это время жизни объекта, которому они принадлежат. Они доступны для любых методов класса (кроме статических методов), и если у них указана область видимости иная, чем `private`, они могут быть доступны и из внешнего мира.

Статическая переменная (aka переменная класса) также описывается внутри описания класса и вне методов, но со словом `static`. В отличие от переменных экземпляра, она существует в единственном экземпляре (общая для всех экземпляров данного класса). Она существует независимо от существования объектов этого класса, с момента загрузки класса (т. е., упрощенно говоря, с первого упоминания этого класса в вашем коде) и до конца работы программы. Она доступна всем методам класса, включая статические, и в зависимости от указания области видимости может быть доступна вне класса.

Переменные экземпляра и статические переменные по умолчанию инициализируютя в нулевое значение (для числовых типов - 0, для `boolean` - `false`, для объектных - `null`), и их можно использовать без явной инициализации.

Переменные метода (правильнее -- локальные переменные) описываются внутри тела методов и существуют только внутри этих методов, только с момента объявления до момента выхода из метода. Существуют также локальные переменные с еще более узкой областью видимости -- если переменная объявлена внутри программного блока (между фигурными скобками), то она видна только в этом блоке. Эти переменные недоступны извне того метода или программного блока, в котором они описаны, и не сохраняют свое значение между вызовами метода или между выполнениями программного блока. Они не инициализируются автоматически, т. е. нельзя пытаться использовать их значение, если это значение перед тем не было им присвоено явно. 
При выходе из метода значения всех локальных переменных теряются. Если внутри метода создавались новые объекты и они не были присвоены каким-то внешним переменным или возвращены в качестве результата, то такие объекты становятся недоступны и впоследствии уничтожаются сборщиком мусора.

Параметры методов, как и локальные переменные, существуют только внутри методов. По сути, это копии тех переменных, которые были переданы методу в качестве фактических параметров при его вызове. Внутри метода им можно присваивать новые значения, но исходные переменные от этого не изменятся. Однако нужно помнить, что объекты при передаче в качестве параметра не копируются, копируется только ссылка на них. Если такой объект изменяется внутри метода (не ссылка на него, а сам объект), то его новое состояние сохранится и после возврата из метода. Если же внутри метода параметру объектного типа присвоено новое значение, то исходный объект от этого не меняется, так же как и в случае с параметрами примитивных типов.

Comment: _По сути, это копии тех переменных, которые были переданы методу_ и потом это кто-то будет с умным видом повторять

Comment: @keekkenen И что? Это плохо?

Comment: неточности это всегда плохо

Comment: @keekkenen Скажите точнее.